# Show that multiplicative functional are extremal points in a $C^*$-algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

I found the following exercise in my lecture notes: Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^*$-algebra. Then every multiplicative functional is an extremal point of $K_1^{\mathcal{A}'}(0)$.

Other than writing $m = t m_1 + (1-t) m_2$ for a multiplicative functional $m$, $t \in (0,1)$ and $m_1,m_2 \in K_1^{\mathcal{A}'}(0)$ and trying to show that $m_1 = m = m_2$, I got nothing. I thought (assuming commutativity) of using the Gelfand-Neimark theorem to identify my $C^*$-algebra with the space of continuous functions. But I was not able to deduce anything from it.

**Question:** What would be a good starting point to tackle the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume first that $A$ is unital.  Then
$$1 = m(\mathbf{1}) = tm_1(\mathbf{1}) + (1-t)m_2(\mathbf{1})$$
and $|m_1(\mathbf{1})|, |m_2(\mathbf{1})|\le 1$ because $\|\mathbf{1}\| = 1$ and $\|m_1\|, \|m_2\| \le 1$ by assumption.  It follows that $m_1(\mathbf{1}) = m_2(\mathbf{1}) = 1$ and $\|m_1\| = \|m_2\| = 1$.

By proposition 1.12.2 of [this](https://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/putnam/ln/C*-algebras.pdf) introduction to $C^*$-algebras, it follows that $m_1, m_2$ are positive linear functionals.  Let $U = \max(\frac{1}{t}, \frac{1}{1-t})$.  If $a\in A, a\ge 0$ then $m_1(a), m_2(a)\ge 0$ so from the equation $m(a) = tm_1(a) + (1-t)m_2(a)$ we conclude that $m_1(a), m_2(a) \le U m(a)$.

By lemma 1.12.3 part 1 of [same](https://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/putnam/ln/C*-algebras.pdf) introduction, for any $a,b\in A$
$$|m_1(b^* a)|^2 \le m_1(a^* a) m_1(b^* b)$$
So now let $a\in A$ such that $m(a) = 0$ and take $b=\mathbf{1}$ (so $m_1(b^* b) = m_1(\mathbf{1}) = 1$).  Then
$$|m_1(a)|^2\le m_1(a^* a) \le U m(a^* a) = U m(a^*) m(a) = 0$$
where $m(a^* a) = m(a^*) m(a)$ by the multiplicativity of $m$.

This proves that $\operatorname{Ker}(m) \subseteq \operatorname{Ker}(m_1)$.  But these are linear functionals, so $\operatorname{Ker}(m)$ is a linear subspace of $A$ of co-dimension $1$, and $m_1\ne 0$ (because $m_1(\mathbf{1}) = 1$).  It follows that $m_1 = m$.

If $A$ is not unital, you can adjoin a unit to $A$ (see [here](https://www.fuw.edu.pl/%7Ederezins/mat-c.pdf), section 2.4.)  I haven't checked the detail, but I believe that by working in the algebra after adjoining a unit to $A$ you can get the result for non-unital $A$ as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, I try to understand it.

Comment: Alright, I think that I understand everything except 2 things (both regarding proposition 1.12.2 you mentioned): First:
Why do we have $\|a + is\| \leq \sqrt{\|a\|^2+s^2}$ ( $= r + s$ in the lemma)?
Second:
Why does $\|\|a\| - a \| \leq \|a\|$ hold. The reference in the document seems to be incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, I was able to answer these questions by myself. Thanks again!